# MYSQL: get all tables and this tables columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

To auto complete logic for my db I need to query all tables in database, but also list of columns for each tables with single request.

So Let's assume I have 2 tables: `Table1` and `T2` and `Table1` have columns: i`d, type, size` and `T2` to have `id, weight, length`. And I need something like

```
[table1, id]
[table1, type]
[table1, size]
[T2, Id]
[T2, weight]
[T2, length]
```

How it's possible to get this info with single query

Comment: not possible like this. you cannot directly use the results of a query as the source for  a table/fields name list. you'll have to dynamically build a query string using the results you get from information_schema, and select each of those tables individually.

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't help us understand what is going on.  What do you expect (or want) to get and what are you getting?

Comment: This is not valid sql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be an answer for the question:

```
select T.Table_name, C.column_name from information_schema.Tables AS T
LEFT JOIN information_schema.COLUMNS as C
ON T.Table_name = C.Table_name
where T.TABLE_SCHEMA = <YOUR_SCHEMA (name of db)>
order by C.ordinal_position
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to query the information_schema, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='<name_of_your_schema>'
```

And, you can also go deeper and get them ordered by foreign key dependency:

```
SELECT col.TABLE_NAME, col.COLUMN_NAME 
FROM information_schema.columns col
LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage kcu 
    ON col.COLUMN_NAME=kcu.COLUMN_NAME
RIGHT JOIN information_schema.tables t
    ON t.TABLE_NAME=kcu.TABLE_NAME
WHERE col.TABLE_SCHEMA='<name_of_your_schema>' GROUP BY t.TABLE_NAME ORDER BY t.TABLE_TYPE DESC, COUNT(kcu.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME) ASC;
```

I have to warn I didn't test this second thought enough times to guarantee much, but it seems to work quite well.